# The single Ajax call made inside the DOM ready function in jQuery is called twice

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using jquery 1.3.2 and have the following code,

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ViewBuilder/GetView",
        data: {
            rId: $("#R_Id").val()
        },
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data !== undefined) {
                var rep = JSON.parse(data);

                if (rep.ViewObjects !== undefined) {
                    for (var ro in rep.ViewObjects) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/ViewBuilder/ViewObject",
                            type: "POST",
                            contentType: "application/json",
                            data: JSON.stringify({
                                Id: ro,
                                TypeId: rep.ViewObjects[ro].TypeId,
                                SourceId: rep.ViewObjects[ro].SourceId,
                                Ordinal: rep.ViewObjects[ro].Ordinal,
                                ViewId: rep.ViewObjects[ro].ViewId
                            }),
                            success: function (data) {
                                if (data !== undefined) {
                                    $('.View-content #column1').append(data)
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I have this ajax call fired twice,
i have used jQuery only once. The document is loaded only once and have seen a lot of Q & A here.. it has beaten my days. kindly point out the buggy code in this fragment, i have literally run out of any ideas than posting here.

**EDIT**

Is there any way in chrome developer tool to find which ajax calls are triggered by what event, so that i can find the root cause for these kind of events.

Comment: chrome developer tools network pane shows some details of requests.

Comment: Do you mean to say that the request goes to /ViewBuilder/GetView or /ViewBuilder/ViewObject twice?

Comment: I actually included my script file that contains this script twice, in different views. Also, while using the draggable and sortable, i get the repeated execution, which is being tracked in a different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try debugging with console.log(). 
You can then see the output in the chrome developers tool console tab.

Hope this helps!